# Changing values of a number picker

Tags: android

I have a number picker with a min and max value set to it. Is there any way at all to change the value of a number to display as a letter such as 1 = a, 2 = b and so on? I only want to do it for an element or two though, the rest would still be regular numbers. Thanks!

Comment: You can do something like: http://www.xonico.com.ar/webtools/ascii_conv.php, then do the subtraction for the letters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes like a switch statement like this.

```
char letter='?';
switch(yournumberfromnumpicker){
    case 1:
        letter='a';
        break;
    case 2:
        letter='b';
        break;
    }
```